# Using Java-based API with Django

Tags: java, python, django, api

I'm in the process of creating a website using Django and want to incorporate data from the Google Play Store (Android Market) into it. I've considered manually scraping the Store but it seems like it might be a slow and tedious process so I decided to consider other options, namely an open-source API called [android-market-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).

The problem with android-market-api is that it is written in Java and only has Ruby/PHP ports (not sure exactly what that means). This is a problem because I want to be able to interact with the API using my existing Python code. How should I proceed with this?

- Should I try to translate the existing code into Python?
- Should I write something in Python that "communicates" with the API
  and translates its outputs into Python code so I can use the results
  with the rest of my apps?
- Should I use some existing intermediary language/module that lets
  Python and Java code interact seamlessly?

Or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a Python Port: [android-market-api-py](https://github.com/liato/android-market-api-py) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

It says on the project description page:

> Main target is java but it can be easily adapted to other languages since it's Google ProtoBuf based.

Therefore, you can tell `protoc` to compile the protobufs for Python, then port over the high-level API. This way you have the best control over your Python port of `android-market-api`.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You install protobufs from Google Code, then compile them for Python. It's all in the protobuf manual. 
As for porting the high-level API, you can use the GitHub project mentioned above as a starting point.